# XMLSerializer cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, xml, maven, servlets, xmlserializer

I am using the following code :

```
         PrintStream out = new PrintStream(response.getOutputStream());  
         DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
         DOCUMENT = documentBuilder.newDocument(); // assign empty XML Document
         Element MESSAGES = DOCUMENT.createElement("MESSAGES");
         Element MESSAGE = DOCUMENT.createElement("MESSAGE");
         Element CONTENT = DOCUMENT.createElement("CONTENT");

         CONTENT.setTextContent("Data content");
         DOCUMENT.appendChild(MESSAGES);
         MESSAGES.appendChild(MESSAGE);
         MESSAGE.appendChild(CONTENT);

         response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
         //set the content type
         response.setContentType("text/xml");

         XMLSerializer xmlserializer = new XMLSerializer(out, null);// Error
         xmlserializer.serialize(DOCUMENT);
```

I am getting the XMLSerializer cannot be resolved to a type . This is Maven code and my pom.xml has

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
    <artifactId>castor</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I am still getting the error as

```
XMLSerializer cannot be resolved to a type
```

Is there any dependency still missing ?

Comment: Remove one of your xercesImpl it is causing a collision

Comment: Tried removing one of the xercesImpl  but still the same error

Comment: What is the fully qualified name of XMLSerializer in your imports?

Comment: I am using import org.apache.xml.serialize.*;